# When did Oda state that a future member of the Straw Hats would be a previous enemy?

Tags: one-piece

I've seen a lot of theory based on this and many people saying so; however, I'm curious as to where it comes from (if there's any official source) or if someone just made it up.

The best hint I could find online was in a discussion on the [One Piece Wikia](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Forum:The_new_member_an_old_enemy!) pointing out that it may have been an old Jump Fiesta interview:

> It was allegedly in an old Jump Fiesta interview (2009ish), but I haven't found a source for it anywhere, and the translation has been disputed (it may have referred to a temporary ally like in Impel Down/Marineford War, rather than an actual crew member). Zodiaque 10:36, June 7, 2012 (UTC)

As long as there isn't a trustworthy source, I'm inclined to believe that Oda didn't mean **CREW MEMBER**.

Comment: I'll have to do more research, but I think this has been a pretty old rumor (since 2006?) which was never confirmed. One thing I am sure off is that it wasn't in the SBS. Some talk about an interview get gave a while back.

Comment: If u consider the 6k pirates from the current straw hat fleet as "straw hats", it might turn out similar to what happened with squardo. I doubt it would be any of the main crew. Then again we havent seen sanji for a year and a half now, so who knows what he and caesar are up to...

Comment: @PeterRaeves I'm not concerned with fleet member, crew member or whatsoever. I want to know if Oda said something like that, his exact words and their meaning.

Comment: @PeterRaeves - since it seems like a really old rumor then I guess it already happened. Perhaps that would be Franky. Yes they fought a lot and Franky stole their money and they nearly killed eachother etc. But I have never heard anyone actually state that rumor anywhere

Comment: depending on how old that rumor is it might even be referring to Robin from way back when.

Answer (score 2):

This is just an old rumor. It's possible Oda said that an old enemy would be a future ally, but it has been off the record for some time now. It's so old in fact, it could have been talking about any number of people and some believe it was a reference to Impel Down, when many of Luffy's old enemies become allies (mainly [Bon Clay](http://koei.wikia.com/wiki/Bon_Clay), [Galdino](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Galdino), and [Buggy](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Buggy)).

As for nakama, it could have possibly been Robin, who was once second-in-command of Baroque Works in [Alabasta](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Alabasta). It could have been referring to Franky, though this is unlikely since he wasn't an enemy for very long.

It is possible that Luffy's crew has reached capacity since [the manga is 80% written](https://kotaku.com/the-one-piece-manga-is-80-percent-finished-says-eiichi-1827796353) (as of 7/23/18) and in the anime, Luffy mentions wanting ["at least 10"](https://kotaku.com/the-one-piece-manga-is-80-percent-finished-says-eiichi-1827796353) nakama (and as of 8/27/18, there are 10 Straw Hats). That being said, there's not likely to be many more newbies, so although it's possible, I wouldn't hold your breath for that "previous enemy" to still be in our future.

***Correction: Luffy wants at least 10 nakama, that doesn't include himself, so with 10 current straw hats, he has 9.